# createsuperuser invalid syntax in Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I ran into a problem while going through my first Django tutorial.

I didn't create an initial superuser account during syncdb and I'm now trying to create it programmatically. The problem is that I'm getting an invalid syntax error when I run the command:

```
>>> django-admin.py createsuperuser
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    django-admin.py createsuperuser
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am running Django through Python tools for Visual Studio 2010.
Both  'django.contrib.auth' and  'django.contrib.admin' are enabled in settings.py.
[Here](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Django%20Web%20Site/Cloud%20Service%20Tutorial) is the tutorial that I'm following.

Comment: are you in the django shell by any chance ?

Comment: That command is supposed to be typed in the terminal. And by the look of it, you are in Python shell or Django shell.
So type `quit()` to quit the shell and try that command again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running the command in the `django shell`. You need to run this command in the command prompt/terminal instead.

Demo

```
(_env)k@dev:~/workspace/prj krav 48 $ ./manage.py shell
In [1]: manage.py createsuperuser
------------------------------------------------------------
   File "<ipython console>", line 1
     manage.py createsuperuser
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Continued..

```
In [2]: exit()
Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)? y
(_env)k@dev:~/workspace/prj krav 48 $ ./manage.py createsuperuser
Username:
```

Comment: I am running it in django shell, I'm not sure how to get the above to work in command prompt though, what directory should I run the command from?

Comment: in the root directory of the project. (wherever your manage.py file resides). Actually, in the same location when you exit from the shell prompt.

Comment: I'm using the shell within visual studio and when I exit the shell and enter the createsuperuser command it just hangs indefinitely until I close it down. Also I can't cd into the project dir in command prompt because project folder resides on a share drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. just open the `cmd` (Command Prompt), `cd` into the directory which has `manage.py` file, and then execute the command `python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: That worked after I added `;C:\Python27` to Windows PATH variable. Thanks!